Why does the voltage follower (Op-amp) placed in between 2 circuits as an intermediate stage?
It provides isolation between 2 stages of any circuit, I am bit satisfied with the reason due to its high input resistance.
What bothers me is , Why does the voltage follower (op amp) is called as the buffer "amplifier" though its input-output voltage gain is unity?
It just follows the voltage right?


Depends a lot on exactly what's inside the two black boxes. But in general it converts a high output impedance to a low one.

It is amplifying something, power.
Sure, it has unity voltage gain, so voltage isn't increased, but it is able to deliver a lot more current to stage 2, current that stage 1 is apparently unable to provide.
Power is \$P\$ is the product of the voltage \$V\$ being presented across something, and the current \$I\$ that the thing demands as a result of having that voltage across it:
$$ P = I \times V $$
If the load (stage 2) is particularly current-hungry, and the voltage source (stage 1) is unable to provide that current, then you need something that is able to provide the necessary current on behalf of stage 1. That is the role of the voltage-follower here, a role often called "buffer". It can provide both the right voltage and the requisite current, or in other words, more power.
If you can't lift a heavy load from the floor onto a table 3 feet off the ground, then you get someone or something much stronger than you to do it for you. The object is lifted the same distance, so there's no "height gain", but your helper can apply the much greater force required to lift it, so you have "force gain".
